# BMA - at what posterior effect probability can we say that a variable has an effect?

Tags: regression, bayesian, model-averaging

in the setting of a Bayesian model averaging, we are not dealing with P--value when we are assesing variable importance, but with the posterior effect probability of each variable. My question is, at what level of posterior effect probability can we say that the variable has an effect on the dependent variable? Is there any generally accepted cutoff or a rule of thumb?

[*Hoeting, J. A., D. Madigan, A. E. Raftery, & C. T. Volinsky (1999):
Bayesian model averaging: A tutorial.*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1009212519) on page 393 (13 of this particular .pdf) claim that posterior effect probabilites of 84 %, 72 % and 78 % indicate that the *evidence (for variable significance) is positive but not strong*.

Do you have any other references which would shed more light on this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [*Havranek, T. , Irsova, Z. and Zeynalova, O. (2018), Tuition Fees and University Enrolment: A Meta‐Regression Analysis.*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/obes.12240) where they quote *Jeffreys, H. (1961) Theory of Probability. 3rd Edition*:

> In interpreting the posterior inclusion probability,we follow Jeffreys (1961).The author categorizes values between 0.5 and 0.75 as weak, values between 0.75 and 0.95 as positive, values between 0.95 and 0.99 as strong, and values above 0.99 as decisive evidence for an effect.`